# Julia BitArray with 128 Bits

Tags: julia, bitarray

I need a Julia BitArray-like object that can encode more than 64 bits, say 128 bits. Does a simple replacement of UInt64 with UInt128 in bitarray.jl work?

Comment: May I ask why you need an 128 bit internal representation rather than a 64 bit one? `UInt64` is good because 64-bit value access is very fast in most modern computers and so makes optimal use of the architecture. Is this object going to be for use in a different architecture of some kind?

Comment: I want to work with a 5x5x5 BitArray for modeling a physical lattice system, which makes 64 insufficient.  I guess I could also use the less efficient Array{Bool}, but I wanted to ask if there is a difference workaround.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a single scalar `Int128` to encode your system? You could look at https://github.com/StefanKarpinski/Cards.jl for inspiration.

Comment: My purpose is indeed to use Int128 to encode my system. Some operations I need are transposes and reverses in BitArray form, which is why I want to turn the Int128 into a BitArray object, perform those operations, and then map back to Int128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information in your comment, the existing `BitArray` would itself serve your needs. Note that `BitArray` uses `UInt64`s internally, but that's not a limitation on the size of the array - it actually stores the bits as a `Vector` of `UInt64`s, so there's no special size limitation. You can create a 5x5x5 `BitArray` with no problem.

```
julia> b = BitArray(undef, 5, 5, 5);

julia> b .= 0;

julia> b[3, 5, 5] = 1
1

julia> b[3, :, :]
5×5 BitMatrix:
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1
```

Maybe this part of the documentation threw you off:

> BitArrays pack up to 64 values into every 8 bytes, resulting in an 8x space efficiency over Array{Bool, N} and allowing some
> operations to work on 64 values at once.

but that's talking about internal implementation details. `BitArray`s are not limited to 8 bytes, so they're not limited to having just 64 values in them either.

Creating a new type of bit array using `UInt128`s would likely not be optimized, and is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I had missed the fact that chunks were an array of UInt64, and not just a single value. Indeed BitArray without any modification suits my purpose.

Comment: I edited the question to better describe my intention.